# Can ++enc=utf-8 be made the default action for :w?

Tags: save, encoding

After pasting text snippets from web sites into an existing Vim file, I often have to save the file with `:w ++enc=utf-8` to avoid a conversion error.

Can that be made the default?

I have set `fileencoding=utf-8` but that does not fix the problem.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise may be you could accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Vim file is a new file created within Vim (e.g. using `:enew`) the default encoding apply.

You can set the default encoding of new buffer as `utf-8` by adding the following line in your `vimrc` file:

```
setglobal fenc=utf-8
```

If the Vim is file already exist Vim will guess the encoding. You can propose to Vim to first try to set the encoding to `utf-8` by setting the `fileencodings` list:

```
set fileencodings=utf-8
```

Comment: Note that I am pasting into an existing file text snippets (from a browser) that can have a different encoding.  The command :w ++enc=utf-8 cleans this up, though it is not obvious to me that it should.

Comment: I have made the suggested changes but it will take some time to see the effects.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I'm not sure I understand correctly what you said about 'sometimes'. Could you elaborate? Do you need to restart Vim, do you need to reload the files? Do you need to ignore the `viminfo` file?

Comment: I have made experiment and I doubt `viminfo` plays a role. The change in the way Vim guess the file encoding should be immediate after Vim restart. Unless you load a session (the `fileencodings` is part of the session information)

Comment: Vivian De Smedt wrote: "I'm not sure I understand correctly what you said about 'sometimes'".  It was "some time", not "sometimes".  I don't have a test case and will have to wait until I next encounter a conversion error.  With luck, that will be never, after making the suggested changes.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :-) When you will be convinced that the solution works feel free to accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: Having made the changes suggested by Vivian De Smedt seems to have solved the problem of getting a conversion error message when trying to save, but now I frequently find that my files are getting marked readonly.  (Because they are read as ascii but getting saved as utf-8?).  That is OK, because it is much easier to type :w! than :w ++enc=utf-8,  a warning seems not unreasonable, and gradually converting all my files to utf-8 is probably a good idea. I'll mark this "solved" if I can figure out how.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) Have a nice week-end.